# Pulling SPy info from nbbo table

Tags: kdb

I have a nbbo table from which i want to pull spy nbbo after certain intervals (10sec,30sec,1min2min,5min) from some specific time for an entire month. I am using the following code but it is taking sometime. Can please someone suggest me some alternative way to go about it

```
dtlist:h"select distinct date from t where strategy=`xxx,date within (2014.05.01,2014.05.30)"

spytab::();
grabspynbbo:{[dt]
tbl:{ distinct h "select date,trade_id,sym:`SPY, linetime:`time$trans_time from t where strategy = `xxx,date = ",string x}[dt];    

    getData:{[tbl] tempNbbo:select from nbbo where date in tbl`date,sym in `SPY,linetime within(09:30t;16:30t);
    t1:select sym,linetime:(linetime+00:00:10t),trade_id from tbl;
    t2:select sym,linetime:(linetime+00:00:30t),trade_id from tbl;
    t3:select sym,linetime:(linetime+00:01:00t),trade_id from tbl;
    t4:select sym,linetime:(linetime+00:02:00t),trade_id from tbl;
    t5:select sym,linetime:(linetime+00:05:00t),trade_id from tbl;
    t6:select sym,linetime:(linetime+00:10:00t),trade_id from tbl;

    t1:`trade_id xkey select trade_id,bbo10s:0.5*(bid+ask) from (aj[`sym`linetime;t1;tempNbbo]);
    t2:`trade_id xkey select trade_id,bbo30s:0.5*(bid+ask) from (aj[`sym`linetime;t2;tempNbbo]);
    t3:`trade_id xkey select trade_id,bbo1m:0.5*(bid+ask) from (aj[`sym`linetime;t3;tempNbbo]);
    t4:`trade_id xkey select trade_id,bbo2m:0.5*(bid+ask) from (aj[`sym`linetime;t4;tempNbbo]);
    t5:`trade_id xkey select trade_id,bbo5m:0.5*(bid+ask) from (aj[`sym`linetime;t5;tempNbbo]);
    t6:`trade_id xkey select trade_id,bbo10m:0.5*(bid+ask) from (aj[`sym`linetime;t6;tempNbbo]);

    (ij/) (t1;t2;t3;t4;t5;t6)  
        };
    h1(getData;tbl)}
    spytab::(uj/)grabspynbbo each dtlist`date
```

I will apppreciate any help. 
Thanks,
Mohit

Comment: Too many unknowns here. What is t? Would it not make more sense to have the date clause first? Are there any atributes on strategy or date cols? Have you profiled the function to determine where the slowdown actually is? Do the aj's conform to the recommended optimal aj conditions?

Comment: t is a table (100k obs) from which i am picking my specific time (for each day). For ex: (09:45:32.50,10:15:45.50) on 2014.05.01 and i need to pull spy nbbo after 10sec,30sec,1min etc from this time onwards. I think the slow is because the one day spy nbbo table contains 11mln obs ans then doing multiple asofjoin so as to get the closest bid/ask at (linetime+00:00:10t). there are no attributes on strategy/date cols. I am not aware of how do we do the profiling of tne function (my apologies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing below two modifications, that should increase speed (also mentioned by terrylynch):

a) Use date condition before strategy condition in where clause (there are 2 queries in your code).

b) Use `` `g# `` and `` `s# `` attributes on your tempNbbo table. That will speed up ``aj by huge amount.

reference: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#aj-aj0-asof-join   (check Remarks Section)